# Installed new Siemens FS140 for surge protection but still receiving power on/off flickers from power surges

Tags: electrical, protection

Installed a new [Siemens FS140](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Dj33YVppDk) for surge protection but still receiving power on/off flickers from power surges.

What can I do to have seamless power protection alongside power delivery so there is never a surge interruption to my devices in-house?

Please provide amazon links to things you would recommend purchasing. I really need to nip this in the bud.

Thank you everyone and have a nice Father's day as well.

Comment: You need brownout protection. Here's one for *six thousand dollars*. https://www.backupbatterypower.com/pages/wiring-diagrams

Comment: Thank you for the response Mazura.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be the whole house nor hard-wired, nor grounded, check out a Goal Zero. Mid range is ~$2k. They start at like $800.

Comment: Well the whole house provides peace of mind. A few years ago I had heard about someone using super-capacitors and whenever there were symptoms like what I am experiencing the system would switch on in an instant to equalize everything. Thank you for providing these options to me.

Comment: I was just doing some research about other ways to mitigate brownout problems and came across 'Line Conditioners'. Does anyone know if that can work alongside a Surge Protector at the panel? Recommendations from amazon are welcome if this is another solution for seamless power delivery and protection.

Comment: For $6k : "The following UPS systems are UL listed and can have their output wired directly to an electrical panel to provide uninterrupted power during outages, voltage regulation, surge suppression, noise filtration, and frequency regulation." "they are always on real-time conditioned backup power provided by the UPS" - this is like industrial equipment.... but given the advancements in Li-Ion, if there's some BS you can buy off of Amazon, I'd like to know. +1

Comment: How long are these flickers? Does your area have underground or overhead electric service?

Comment: Howdyhowdy line conditioners are exactly that they can filter unwanted noise or transients but other than UPS equipment there is no real way to eliminate line transient and switch overs. Capacitors can buffer DC dropouts if large enough but won’t help on the AC side.

Comment: Peace of mind may be expensive: you can spend far more than $6K - or possibly get a deal. Some utilities offer lease arrangements on *e.g.* Tesla Powerwall so they can use them for peaking power. Then again, if cost is no object, you can just buy a few. If cost IS an object, you can get (or make from component, listed, parts) a "dual conversion" UPS sized for the actual critical load (dual conversion - a grid-powered battery charger charges a battery bank that an inverter connects to to power the load - no switching. Not cheap, either. Most loads can use a normal UPS that switches quickly.)

Comment: Please take the [tour] - product recommendations are specifically off topic here. There is a stack for those, but it's a cesspit wasteland IMHO (crazy policy of "there can be only one answer" and a cult culture to go with it.)

Comment: What kinds of devices do you need to protect this way? Short power glitches are way easier to handle on the DC side of any power supplies involved. How long interruptions are we talking about, less than a second or more?

Answer (score 3):

A surge suppressor deals with surges (over-voltage.)

If you have dropouts (under-voltage, brief outages) you would expect exactly nothing from a surge suppressor, other than perhaps clamping the often-associated overvoltage when power comes back on.

A surge capacitor (I use both) primarily deals with *faster* surges (and RFI - indeed, the item is labeled as a facility EMI filter.) It will not solve dropouts either. AC voltage changes from *positive to zero to negative to zero to positive* 60 times per second, and the capacitor does too - when the input voltage stops, the capacitor will just head to 0 volts in an average time of 8 milliseconds or less.

You require a UPS - if your loads are **really** so finicky that a normal UPS switching time upsets them (unusual) you need a dual-conversion or "online" UPS. Those are expensive, and inefficient (conversions are not 100% efficient, so you always lose a few percent of the power as waste heat.)

Product recommendations are very specifically off topic.