# How to protect house hold electric appliances from mishaps

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, appliances, voltage, surge-suppression

I have so many electric appliances installed at my home.

I have been recently reading in newspapers that some electric appliance are getting affected due to high or low voltage or short circuit issues or lighting strike on home/nearby electrical pole or issue at grid

I have circuit breakers installed at my home already.

Basically I'd like to prevent any electrical related issues that can affect my electrical equipments(Washing machine , AC , Fridge, TV , OTG , Water heater, Dishwasher etc..  ).

**Update 1:**

Please find the detailed house Electrical load in an [excel sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Ac1n4SJiBAL6SPocB4JqClSNBwBLXQ-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106354200081003577526&rtpof=true&sd=true) this is really detailed and I have spent so much time preparing this :)

*Please know that my house is powered by 3 phase power supply due to higher electrical load*

[image]

*Please find my electrical circuit distribution*

[image]

[image]

*Please find UPS supply inverter ( 150 Amp 90 Watts ) details below*

[image]

*Please find my electrical grid supply details below*

[image]

**Update 2:**

So far I had to come across following issues.

- My apple laptop plug became useless I don't know how (In Bedroom 2 )
- There was an extension box plug and it caught on fire ( In Bedroom 2)

  [image]
- There was a plug of DTH antenna that became useless just in 3 days of installation ( TV electrical Unit )
- I had to replace some tube-lights so far which are not even two years old. ( Hall , Outside Electrical unit , Dining room )
- I have faced electrical tripping multiple times from Bedroom 2
- My [8+2 Giga Port AI PoE Switch](https://trueview.co.in/product/82-giga-port-ai-poe-switch/) for CCTV - IP cams and NVR is dead , the repair guy mentioned the switch got short circuited , this happened couple of weeks ago

  [image]

Comment: For starters, a circuit breaker doesn't do the same job as a surge protector.  You can also look up something called an active power conditioner, but those are expensive ($500+) and meant for sensitive electronics like high end stereo equipment.

Comment: Will there be low voltage issues affecting the appliances ? I know high voltage affects , is there anything else that affects the appliances ? WIll one surge protector , prevent all these issues ? or any other accessory must be bought as well ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A lot depends on the situation. For example high/low voltage - if nominal is 240V, most equipment will handle 220V - 250V without a problem, but some will have problems (which requires an active power conditioner). But some places have serious brownouts - drop below 200V and a lot of equipment will have problems (but not all - a lot of modern electronics will run fine 100V - 250V). Need more details on *actual* problems in a specific location and *actual* equipment involved to figure out a real-world solution (or whether any "solution" is needed at all).

Comment: [Installed new Siemens FS140 for surge protection but still receiving power on/off flickers from power surges](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/227649/installed-new-siemens-fs140-for-surge-protection-but-still-receiving-power-on-of) "You need brownout protection. Here's one for six thousand dollars."

Answer (score 8):

Go through your house with a fine-tooth comb and make sure every aspect is fully compliant with modern European electrical codes. *No exceptions*.

The classic thing in the developing world is shoddy electrical that just barely works but falls short of the mark on every electrical inspection.

Use appliances which are tested and approved by a competent 3rd party testing lab such as UL, BSI, TUV and the like. Might be a good time to be a European appliance snob.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer, but question is a bit broad.

I think the best thing you can do is to study the electrical wiring practices of countries/cities with more mature codes and construction practices and try and follow as much of that as you can.  India is a huge place, so I'm not trying to disparage your building/home, but there's everything from hand assembled shacks, to world class office buildings.  There's also a huge difference in how things are wired.

Using the right wire sizes, having your loads divided into reasonable circuits and having proper overload and GFI/RCD protection will go a long way to having a safe home.  Proper wire connections made in approved enclosures is also important and commonly overlooked in rural or less developed areas.

I'm sure that some of the issues you read about in the paper can be traced back to poor wiring practices.  An AC unit should trip a breaker if the compressor shorts out, not overheat and explode.  Accidents like that almost never happen in areas with strict electric code (although there are always people that do unsafe work on their own).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent overvoltage:
Install cascaded surge supressors.
Type I + II (or whatever its called at Your place) for the whole house/flat at the main electrical junction box - they are large and expensive, so it might be hard to fit them in.
Protect sensitive appliances with surge protector strips - that is, all computers/tvs need to be plugged into power strips with fuses and varistors. High power appliances like dishwasher/AC/heaters generally do not need power strips for protection (and will actually burn the surge protectors sometimes).

To protect from undervoltage:
Most appliances will just work with too low voltage or just fail to start and turn off. There is not much you can do - you can install UPS for smoothing the sudden voltage dips, but it won't last long if the low voltage condition continues.
If you can get a hold on an old fashion voltage stabilizer - a hevay box with a dial to set voltage, that would help. These were popular in old times when voltage was too low for some TV's.
Heaters, AC, refrigerators etc do not need any special care with low voltage. Dishwasher might restart, but you won't find ups sized to handle those anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer to this is , **SPD ( Surge Protection Device )** for the whole home.

This gives ranges of benefits.

- Prevents high voltage and current issue due to lightning strike or some Electrical grid level issue.
- Prevent low voltage and current issue.

So basically install this SPD near to Main electricity board once the electric supply is through the SPD then

- You can have **GFCI**(Ground Fault Circuit interrupter) aka RCD(Residual circuit device) or GFI

  This is to trip when somebody is electrocuted
- You Can have **Circuit breakers** after the GFCI

  This is to trip when there's a short circuit I mean overcurrent
- Also remember to have **3 Phase Electrical Selector Switch**

This is to split the electric supply to different parts of the house and isolate if there is any electrical issue

**Please note**

- Consider having the important and less energy consuming appliances under Residential UPS Inverter Battery such as TV , CCTV Recorder , Laptop,computer and mobile electrical socket. The inverter usually regulates electrical anomalies like High/low voltage , high/low current,frequency related issues and supply energy from battery if required.
- Always Run the AC with Stabilizer
- Buy the fridge,washing machine,OTG/Oven,TV with built-in inverter or stabilizer.
- Try to use high quality Surge protector box with surge protection for appliances just another layer of protection. ( Buy the Genuine surge protector - It protects you from both high/low current and voltage )

**Update:**

- If you building is taller or in isolated places then consider installing **Lightning Arrester** and make sure you are grounding the electricity atleast 5 feet away from the building walls because voltage of lightning would be in thousands when the electicity is near to **building wall columns** , the **rebar** in those columns might conduct the electricity and it might melt and weaken the integrity of the building columns
- Install **AFCI**( Arc Fault Circuit Interupter ) to prevent Electrical Arc issues

Comment: Do we need AFCI when there's circuit breaker ?

Comment: Yes , also you can choose to go with PON breaker ( Power On Neutral ) this acts as combination breaker i.e GFCI +AFCI

Comment: I should use PON breaker in place of GFCI plus AFCI or I should use PON breaker in conjunction with GFCI + AFCI

Answer (score 1):

Over- and under-voltages come from the utility grid outside of your home, short circuits generally happen inside your home or your appliance because of low-quality wiring.

Short circuits are easy(-er). Just make sure to have sane wiring (including grounding), reputable brand circuit breakers and (highly recommended) GFCI/RCD prorection. As Harper said, strictly following the electrical code from an European country of your choice is a good start.

Overvoltages are invariably bad and they destroy appliances. Overvoltages are usually transient (but your mileage may vary, depending on where you are).

Undervoltages (also called brownouts) are safer... to an extent. Some appliances simply stop working, others run at reduced performance and yet some (e.g. containing a specific types of motors) fail to work or work at reduced performance but they also overheat, sometimes up to the point of catching fire if left powered for prolonged time with insufficient voltage. Undervoltages may be either transient or prolonged, or in some cases, pretty much the default state of things in a particular area.

Be also aware that different appliances have profoundly different tolerances for both under- and over-voltages. I.e. the fact that something runs without issues from a particular power source does not mean that something else will not fail.

What can be done, then?

Making good electricity out of bad electricity is quite a complex task that does not have a general solution.

0. You may as well simply not care, unless something breaks. Quite often this is the cheapest and safe enough option. If your area is known for recurring electricity problems, the option may neither be safe nor the cheapest in the long run, so read on.
1. Demand a better service from your utility or from authorities that are expected to regulate utilities. This usually fails, esp. if done without a great number of supporters that can mount a political pressure. When done right, this is the most effective option in the long run.
2. Use surge protectors, at least for the expensive gear. This will spare you from transient overvoltages, but the surge protectors generally require to be manually reset after an overvoltage event (or even replaced in some cases). There is an additional problem that most surge protectors sold everywhere are, in fact, fake. Sorry to say it. It is not easy to check if a surge protector works, so most of them simply don't and this goes unnoticed (for a while).
3. Use voltage stabilizers, at least for the expensive gear. Be aware that they quickly become expensive themselves if you need higher power capacity.
4. Use uninterruptible power supplies, at least for the expensive gear. They generally have the surge protection and the voltage stabilizing functions built-in. They are also pretty much a commodity so one can have them cheaper than a voltage stabilizer of the same capacity. On the other hand, they have batteries that need to be replaced once in a while.

Comment: Thanks , How do we find if Surge Protectors are Genuine and not fake ? Because even fake products have CE mark.

Comment: @CuriousMan Contact the mfgr with the serial number to register your product. If they tell you that it's A) an invalid serial number or B) that it's already been registered, you know you've got a fake. If you don't hear that, then you've got a legit product (or at least the first forgery with that S/N to be registered...).

Answer (score 1):

If you have three phase power to the home and some of your appliances die in a suspicious manner while there doesn't seem to be any thunderstorm or other obvious culprit, you may have a loss of neutral.

In 230V countries, there is 230VAC between each phase and neutral, and there's 400VAC between two phases.

If there is a shoddy connection on the neutral wire, then the standard 230VAC no longer applies and appliances wired between phase and neutral find themselves "in series" with other appliances wired between neutral and another phase. In this case each will get a share of the 400VAC voltage between phases. If a low power appliance ends up in series with a high power appliance, the low power one will get most of the voltage, and since it is not designed for 400VAC usually bad things will happen.

If the loss of neutral is intermittent and comes from a bad connection, you may measure the normal voltage in your sockets but who knows when it will decide to manifest again.

The solution is to check all the wiring and take the time to upgrade what is needed to modern standards. It is likely that you will find all sorts of other problems like loose screws waiting to start a fire too.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/lost-neutral-experience-mats-karlsson/

https://www.morganinspectionservices.com/lost-neutral/

https://library.e.abb.com/public/f76d65081d5d887148257ac9001bdd30/Effect%20of%20neutral%20loss%20in%20LV%20networks.pdf

Comment: Interesting to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to protect your electrical appliances for a myriad of possible issues?

There is ONLY one sure way....unplug them.

It does sound as if you have issues with the wiring and basic electrical service at your home.  That should be inspected by a licensed electrician.

Comment: What I feel is somehow the electrical load is not properly divided by trippers. Could you have a look through the excel sheet and let me know your suggestion ?

Comment: My suggestion is call an electrician. I am not one.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'unevenly divided loads'. If you are not burning one of your main fuses all the time, it is not a problem. Your power supply may be. Check for lost neutral. Install surge protection for whole installation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out lost neutral and surge protection.